# After using cocoapods, each run Xcode will compile all without modification file

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, cocoapods

When I delete the DerivedData folder,XCode has recovered to normal.

When I change Build Configuration, XCode will compile all without modification file each Run.

How to solve this problem ？